# Extend cart_items_info function from mod.cartthrob.php

Tags: cartthrob

the `mod.cartthrob.php` has the `cart_items_info` function.

On that function I have

```
    foreach ($data as &$row)
    {
        $row['cart_count'] = $count;
        $row['cart_total_results'] = $total_results;
        $row['first_row'] = ($count === 1) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $row['last_row'] = ($count === $total_results) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        //added by me
        $row['conversion_rate'] = $this->EE->cartthrob->store->config('Cartthrob_stripe_settings')['stripe_conversion_rate'];

        $count++;
    }
```

But the `stripe_conversion_rate` key was added by me in the file. I don't think this is the way, because I should not edit the core files. So in my case how can I add that key so in the html file to have access to `conversion_rate`:

```
{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
  {conversion_rate}
   ..........
```

Answer (score 1):

CartThrob does not allow you to modify any of its tag functions. In this case you're better off creating your own small plugin which returns the value of `$this->EE->cartthrob->store->config('Cartthrob_stripe_settings')['stripe_conversion_rate'];`.